# Public Active directory for testing

Tags: c#, linq, testing, active-directory

I need to write some .NET code for listing user and groups. I am planing to use LINQ. I do not have access to the Active directory for testing. I do not have a server and can not set up my own Active directory. Are there any public Active directory that I could use for testing. The code is only reading data from the Active directory and not writing any data.

Comment: I am more than interested about this as I want to implement some unit tests for an activedirectory python module and I would like to be able to run these tests on Travis, which means I need an internet facing AD. That's open source so paying for a VM hosting and Windows licenses would be an unacceptable solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think AD is the sort of thing you would find a public server to develop against.

Best would be to run either ADAM or AD as a virtual machine on your dev box. Neither require much processor or RAM.

Comment: +1 for the virtual machine suggestion - you can even download an 180 days evaluation version of Windows Server 2008 R2 at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a4fbe2f3-45dd-46bf-8747-16a111c04107&displaylang=en and start it up in Microsoft Virtual PC.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [ADAM (Active Directory Application Mode)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775952%28WS.10%29.aspx) which will install and run on XP and Vista (not sure about 7).  ADAM behaves a little differently than AD, but it may fit your need.

Comment: The Microsoft download page for ADAM does not support Vista. I would still like to know if there is a public AD server.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can install a local [ADAM](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/adam/default.mspx) instead of a full-blown AD.

Answer (score 0):

There is a related question in [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/108473/easiest-way-to-get-an-active-directory-server-for-testing), but it doesn't adds much. The solutions apparently are the same.

I think the solution of a virtual machine is great for me, because in my company the internet connection is restricted and using a publicly accesible AD is out of the question.